Kubernetes - Ingress : Keeps getting 404 not found even though the controller seems to find the service
I'm practicing with Ingress and I,m hitting a wall regarding the setup to access my API.
I'm using Docker Desktop, so it's a single node cluster on my machine.
I started by applying the deployment for the API as follow :
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployement
  namespace: usinebebe
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api-container
          image: usinebebe_api
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

Then I configured a cluster ip service :
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service
  namespace: usinebebe
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: api-app
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP

Then, after applying a nginx controller (this one : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.8.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml), I applied an Ingress :
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-usinebebe
  namespace: usinebebe
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.usinebebe.com
      secretName: ingress-cert  
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-service
            port:
              number: 8081

I added the host specified in the Ingress in my host file.
When I check the logs of the controller I see the request being pick up by Ingress and routing to the service :

Though when I look at the IP of the service, it doesn't match the one I see in the logs :

The IP I find in the controller logs is  10.1.0.71 And the one I find for the service is 10.111.16.54
I also set up a nodeport service like so :
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service-nodeport
  namespace: usinebebe
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: api-app
  ports:
  - port: 8080 
    targetPort: 8080 
    nodePort: 30500 

And it's working perfectly when I use the url http://localhost:30500/swagger/index.html
Any ideas what I'm missing ?

From the [tag:kubernetes] tag wiki: KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here.

It seems, mismatch the IPs in the controller logs and the service. For that check the Service is of type ‘clusterIP’ used by the Ingress. Check the Service IP in the logs matches the service you wanted.
To check Service Endpoints are correctly pointing to the pods by following the command
Kubectl get endpoints -n usinebebe api-service
To check ingress controller logs for details on routing issue
Kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx-controller

For more resource information use ‘kubectl describe’ like below
kubectl describe ingress -n usinebebe api-ingress,
kubectl describe service -n usinebebe api-service
If the application is running on an IIS web server which you enabled, uninstall the IIS web server from windows.
